# Can i manage old web role with new azure sdk?

Tags: azure, azure-configuration

I already have my azure web role running in cloud using azure sdk 1.6. I want to use sdk 1.7 to try new features. If i install sdk 1.6, can i still manage my old web role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure SDK 1.7 is side by side compatible with Windows Azure SDK 1.6. When you install the SDK and use it to create an application you will be give a chance to choose which SDK you want as below:

[image]

On 64bit Windows machine, new SDK 1.7 is installed here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\2012-06
```

This way you can manage your previous Windows Azure SDK 1.6 based code and try and use new Windows Azure SDK 1.7 based features side by side.

You sure can keep running your Windows Azure Web Role with Windows Azure SDK 1.6 however if you decided to upgrade it to Windows Azure 1.7 based Web Role, then you just need to follow the same steps as you do to any other SDK update.